# How to get error information using roslibjs

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using roslibjs and rosbridge--I'd like to get more information when there is an error, particularly when connecting.
My code is:

ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
url: robotUrl
});

ros.on('error', function(error) {
console.log ('Error connecting to websocket server: ' , error);
});

When an error occurs, I see in the debugger that the variable "error" contains a very involved structure, and I guess the actual error message is in there somewhere, but where?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209027/how-to-get-error-information-using-roslibjs/) by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error variable is should always be a string. You can concatenate it in the `console.log` statement and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on 2015-05-12**:
When I concatenate the error variable (here's the code):  "console.log ('Error connecting to websocket server: ' + error);", the result is: "Error connecting to websocket server: [object Event]"  Looks like the argument called error is an Event rather than a string?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-05-12**:
Strange, what if you just log the error variable by itself? console.log(error);, this is based off a working example: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/examples/simple.html#L19

**Comment by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on 2015-05-12**:
In that case, I get: "Event {path: Array[0], cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true, srcElement: WebSocket, defaultPrevented: false…}"  This is clickable and expands to show lots of properties.  Incidentally, the debugger shows that roslib.js (line 651?) has the message.  Or, at least, a message.